# @media screen not applying the right styles on the right screen size

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following media query codes:

```css
//First
@media screen and (min-width: 357px) and (max-width: 910px) { 
    #questionBreadcrumb {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;

        .breadcrumbs {
            > div {
                display: inline-flex;
                align-items: center;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Second
@media screen and (min-width: 911px) {
    #questionBreadcrumb {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;

        .breadcrumbs {
            > div {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow when I scale my screen up to 800px the first media query is applied correctly. But when I get to 804px it started using the second media query.

Can someone tell me or point to me what I'm doing wrong? It might be something so small but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    #questionBreadcrumb {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;

        .breadcrumbs {
            > div {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
        }
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 910px) { 
    #questionBreadcrumb {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;

        .breadcrumbs {
            > div {
                display: inline-flex;
                align-items: center;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you change and how will this fix the problem, which was what by the way?

Answer (score 0):

I think u wrong in write the css code, so the media queries didn't work. I edit this for recommend

From this :

```
    .breadcrumbs {
> div {
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Shoyld be :b

```
 .breadcrumbs  div {
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 }
```

Comment: Why do you believe this is the problem?